# Intuition for a uniform space?

Tags: general-topology, definition, intuition, uniform-spaces

Uniform spaces are topological spaces with additional structure that is used to define uniform properties such as completeness, uniform continuity and uniform convergence.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space#Uniformity), there are five equivalent definitions of a uniform space.

My question is: **What is the concept of uniform space useful for**? What is the intuition for that?

And what is a "**uniformity of a function**"? (One of my professors mentioned it.) Does it have to do anything with uniform spaces? (The context was something like describing some spaces using "uniformity of a function", I dont remember exactly.)

Thank you!

Comment: I haven't yet a formal answer to your problem. But one aspect of understanding uniform space could be a generalization of metric space. One way to see this is that a pseudometric can define a uniform structure (_entourages_), so you can measure the "distance" between two points. More general for a uniform structure, this notion is realised by considering how small an entourage could be that contains the couple $(x,y)$.

Comment: One of the most important feature is that (exceirpt from the Wikipedia article) "a typical entourage is drawn as a blob surrounding the "y = x" diagonal"

Comment: Bourbaki's "General topology" (part 1) includes historical notes on uniform spaces, which explains the motivation and evolution of the topic. About "uniformity of a function" -- probably your professor mean a uniformly continuous function?

Comment: I just saw you have asked (almost) the same question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4246978 3 months ago and you have had an answer that you have validated. In such a case, at least, please, refer to it...